# Предложение или нет?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Предположим есть список людей, сдавших деньги на ремонт:

> **Список**
>   Иванов — 100 руб
>   Петров — 200 руб
>   Сидоров — 300 руб

Можно ли конструкцию "**Иванов — 100 руб**" трактовать как предложение? Или это просто запись "Фамилия — сумма" с тире между ними, и о предложении нельзя говорить? Или здесь возможна двоякая интерпретация?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю,что такие конструкции - полноправные предложения. А почему нет?

Предложение - это высказывание о чем-либо в виде сообщения, вопроса или побуждения. У нас имеется сообщение: Иванов сдал 100 рублей.

Предложение имеет определенное строение (структуру), ядром которой является грамматическая основа. Структура есть: фамилия - сумма, где фамилия -
 подлежащее, сказуемое пропущено, но легко подставляется (сдал), сумма -
 дополнение, входящее в состав пропущенного сказуемого.

Предложение - единица общения. Наша конструкция используется для общения.

Предложение характеризуется интонацией законченности. Наше предложение закончено.

Предложение имеет лексическое и грамматическое значения. Конструкция соответствует критерию - оформлена лексически и синтаксически.

Грамматическое значение предложения - это общее значение предложений. У нас фамилия и сумма, которую внёс человек с этой фамилией.

Всем критериям предложения конструкция соответствует. Даже таблица - это статистическое предложение, где левая часть - подлежащее, а правая - сказуемое. Не являются предложением только названия, вывески и подобное, т.к. там нет сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

В Правилах пунктуации относительно тире (https://therules.ru/dash/#175) среди приведённых примеров случая, подобного вашему, не встречается: список по форме не корректен, и трактовать его как предложение (или предложение из трёх других) нельзя из-за неверного употребления тире.

Уместно перейти на табличную форму или, при небольшом количестве перечисляемых, указывать денежные суммы в скобках: Иванов И.И. (100 р.) и т. д.

(Употреблять сокращения  *руб*.  и  *коп*.  взамен  *р*.  и  *к*.  допустимо лишь в изданиях для малоподготовленного читателя.)